# How to improve a VBA macro that is reading a file slowly

Tags: excel, vba, file, split

On a recent project I need to read from a file that contains around 5K lines.

Each line has different fields and I need to collect some of them into specific cells in excel. Example of one line:

> data1;data2;data3; ..... ;dataN\r

`N` can be as large as 600.

Currently I'm opening the file and looping through each line, splitting by ";" and saving.

What I need is an example:

```
avarSplit = Split(sBuf, ";")

Range("C" & i).Value = CDbl(avarSplit(meter))
```

This tends to be extremely slow and I already have,

`Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual`

Comment: Did you turn off screenupdating as well?  It would help get answers if you could include more of your code: it's not clear what's going on in the line where you're populating the values to the sheet.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend asking VBA to open the file as a delimited text file (the equivalent of File->Open, select , then choosing 'delimited' and ';' in the open text file wizard).  If you need to see how to do that in VBA, record a macro, then open it manually.  Then you have your split values in a temporary workbook, and can copy them into your worksheet as before.

Answer (score 1):

5k lines, even with 600 columns shouldn't take that long.  It's likely that the hold up is writing the values to the cells.  It would be better to fill a two-dim output array and write the values to the spreadsheet all in one go.  Here's an example.

```
Sub ReadTextFile()

    Dim sFile As String
    Dim lFile As Long
    Dim vaLines As Variant, vaSplit As Variant
    Dim aOutput() As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim sInput As String

    sFile = MyDocs & "Book4.csv"
    lFile = FreeFile

    'Read in data
    Open sFile For Input As lFile
    sInput = Input$(LOF(lFile), lFile)
    'Split on new line
    vaLines = Split(sInput, vbNewLine)

    'Set up output array - split is zero based
    'but you want 1-based to write to cells
    ReDim aOutput(1 To UBound(vaLines, 1) + 1, 1 To 1)

    'loop through lines
    For i = LBound(vaLines) To UBound(vaLines)
        If Len(vaLines(i)) > 0 Then
            'split on delimiter
            vaSplit = Split(vaLines(i), ";")
            'store want you want in the output array
            aOutput(i + 1, 1) = vaSplit(15)
        End If
    Next i

    'write the output array to a range
    Sheet1.Range("A2").Resize(UBound(aOutput, 1), UBound(aOutput, 2)).Value = aOutput

End Sub
```

Comment: It's more than 600 columns, if my understanding is good, there are 600 values separated by semi-colons, so it would be more about ~3k columns.